# Python IOError, cannot find file in directory

Tags: python

I'm supposed to upload a database for an assignment, but I'm having a problem. These are the instructions:

> This application will read the mailbox data (`mbox.txt`) count up the
>   number email messages per organization (i.e. domain name of the email
>   address) using a database with the following schema to maintain the
>   counts.
>
> `CREATE TABLE` Counts (`org TEXT`, `count INTEGER`) When you have run the
>   program on `mbox.txt` upload the resulting database file above for
>   grading. If you run the program multiple times in testing or with
>   different files, make sure to empty out the data before each run.
>
> The data file for this application is the same as in previous
>   assignments: http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox.txt.
>
> Because the sample code is using an `UPDATE` statement and committing
>   the results to the database as each record is read in the loop, it
>   might take as long as a few minutes to process all the data. The
>   commit insists on completely writing all the data to disk every time
>   it is called.

The error message that it keeps sending me is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    fh = open(fname)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mbox.txt'
```

I saved them both in the same folder.

Can anybody help with this?

The code that I entered is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zeab.png)

Comment: In the instructions, it also says: "You can use this code as a starting point for your application: [http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/emaildb.py][1]."

Comment: Are you running your code from the directory where you saved them?

Comment: First think to learn with any language is to read the error message (good you put it here). It is answering your problem: your code is unable to find a file named 'mbox.txt'.

Comment: @nk55 post code using code editor {}.pls don't post image of code.

Comment: @nk55: your code shows that you want to open 'mbox.archive'. Do you want to read it? If yes, then it should be in the same folder from where started the Python interpreter; check that. If you are trying to write to a new file with this name, use the 'w' flag with open().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is having problem to find the file `mbox.txt`. It has nothing to do
with anything in the database as you did not run so far yet.

Good practice (at least during development) is to make sure, the things you
hope are true are really true. For this purpose I would use following code
which makes sure, the file really exists.

```
import os.path

fname = "mbox.txt"

assert os.path.exists(fname), "The file shall exist"
```

If you happen to run the code in situation, the file does not exist, it will throw an
`AssertionError` telling you what went wrong.

This exception is very practical as it will tell you quickly what assumption does not holds true and
you know, what to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for a file called `mbox.txt` and not finding it. My guess is that `open(fname)` is looking for `mbox.txt` in the current directory, but the code is being run from a different directory.

Something like this might help resolve your issue:

```
import os

# figure out directory of the Python file
mdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# assuming that mbox.txt is in the same folder as the Python file,
# get the path to that file
mpath = os.path.join(mdir, 'mbox.txt')

# open the file
with open(mpath, 'r') as fh:
    # ...
```

Another approach is using command line arguments. Perhaps there are other files like `mbox.txt` that you want to work with. In these cases, you could accept the path to `mbox.txt` as a command line option:

```
import argparse

argp = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='foo the mbox')
argp.add_argument('mbox_path', help='Path to mbox file')

opts = argp.parse_args()

with open(opts.mbox_path, 'r') as fh:
    # ...
```

Or get fancier and use [`argparse.FileType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) for the `type` argument to `argparse.add_argument`.